# ExtJS 4.2.1 - horizontal line of a single value in chart

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs-chart

I usually got charts something like this

[image]

where i have e.g. for my Target line a complete series.
This works like a charm.

Though sometimes i have to just compare various things with each other and only got ONE(!) X value. Therefore i also got only one value for my target line and so my series cannot draw the line between points and the result looks like this

[image]

I would need an approach for displaying a horizontal line in this case for my target line. the line should also be shown in the legend. Didnt find anything in the web.

Comment: There is a Plugin for Extjs4 - `Ext.ux.chart.ThresholdLineRange`. In ExtJS 5 the feature is included.

Comment: is there also an option to add something in the legend ? because with the plugin its not.

Comment: I think you can just add a label around the line

Comment: i do not want a label around the line.. i need an entry in the extjs chart legend. would this be possible with the highchart lib ?

Comment: its possible to add an empty series to the chart config and so i get the legend entry.